# hyperref Forms with serif font problem

Tags: hyperref, luatex, textfield, format

I use LuaLaTeX.

This MWE works with sans-serif fonts, i.e. Calibri (on Windows)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\fntname{Calibri}
\setmainfont{\fntname}
\usepackage[pdfstartview = FitH]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\def\textfield{123gzZ}
\textfield

\def\fieldname{fieldname}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[
name = \fieldname,
format = {
    this.getField('\fieldname').textFont = '\fntname';
%   this.getField('\fieldname').defaultStyle.fontFamily = ["\fntname", "serif"];
},
value = \textfield,
]
{}% fieldlabel
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

With serif fonts, i.e. `\def\fntname{Times New Roman}` (on Windows), font applies only for pure text (first line), but not for TextField in Form (second line).
Why?

I've tried to use `this.getField('\fieldname').defaultStyle.fontFamily = ["\fntname", "serif"];` (readed from the JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference), but nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: How or where is the `Form` environment defined?

Comment: ```Form``` environment is defined in package ```hyperref```, I use it in a common way.

Comment: With `\def\fntname{Calibri}\setmainfont{\fntname}`, the first line of output employs Calibri, while the second line employs Latin Modern Sans. With `\def\fntname{Times Roman}` (on Mac OS), the second line still employs Latin Modern Sans. Is the use of Latin Modern Sans intended?

Comment: The problem is with font name: "Times New Roman" suits for `\setmainfont` command, but for JavaScript font name without spaces is needed, i.e. "TimesNewRoman" works properly.
So the problem is solved.